# Duvida em PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, configuração

Comecei a usar o `PHPMailer`, e está funcionando mas gostaria de saber se há como o remetente ser o e-mail que o usuário digitou no meu formulário.

Observação: Ele envia os dados do formulário campo: nome,assunto e mensagem.

Segue a configuração que está:

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'meuemailaqui@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'senha';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  //$mail->FromName = 'teste';
  //$mail->From = 'teste012017@hotmail.com';
  $mail->setFrom('teste012017@gmail.com', 'teste');
  $mail->addAddress('meuemailaqui@gmail.com');
  $mail->Subject = 'E-mail PHPMailer';
  $mail->Body = '<h1>Mensagem enviada via PHPMailer</h1>';

  if($mail->Send()){
      echo 'Enviado com sucesso !';
  }else{
      echo 'Erro ao enviar Email:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use esta linha

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($emailFrom, $nameFrom);
```

Sendo que `$emailFrom` e `$nameFrom` são valores que vem do form e você recebe como variáveis.

Comment: Testei como solicitou e sem sucesso. O e-mail que estou recebendo ainda está eu como remetente.

Comment: Você está usando o servidor do Gmail para enviar as mensagens e os termos proíbem enviar emails de fora da rede. Esta linha coloca os dados do remetente no campo "responder para", de forma a facilitar o contato e identificação.

Comment: Vlw! Testei aqui funcionou como vc explicou... Mas existe alguma forma de receber o remetente com o e-mail que o usuário digitar?

Comment: Isso vai depender do provedor. No caso, você usa o Gmail, então, não pode. Se você usasse um provedor que permitisse, então, bastaria fazer algo similar a esta linha: `$mail->setFrom($emailFrom, $nameFrom);`

Comment: Blz! Entendi... Muito obrigado parça.